# Correctly override "settings.xml" in Jenkinsfile Maven build on kubernetes?

Tags: maven, jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

We are setting up a Jenkins-based CI pipeline on our Kubernetes cluster (Rancher if that matters) and up to now we have used the official `maven:3-jdk-11-slim` image for experiments.  Unfortunately it does not provide any built-in way of overriding the default settings.xml to use a mirror, which we need - preferably just by setting an environment variable.  I am not very familar with kubernetes so I may be missing something simple.

Is there a simple way to add a file to the image?  Should I use another image with this functionality built in?

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml """
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kaniko
spec:
  containers:
  - name: maven
    image: maven:3-jdk-11-slim
    command:
    - cat
    tty: true
  - name: kaniko
.... etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to override a file inside `pod` you can use [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/) to store the changed file and mount it instead of previous one.

You can create the ConfigMap from a file using

```sh
kubectl create configmap settings-xml --from-file=settings.xml
```

Your `pod` definition might look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kaniko
spec:
  containers:
    - name: maven
      image: maven:3-jdk-11-slim
      command:
      - cat
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-settings
        mountPath: /usr/share/maven/ref/settings.xml
  volumes:
    - name: config-settings
      configMap:
        # Provide the name of the ConfigMap containing the files you want
        # to add to the container
        name: settings-xml
...
```

Comment: This was what we ended up doing.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

**Summary**: you can mount **your** settings.xml file on the pod at some specific path and use that file with command `mvn -s /my/path/to/settings.xml`.

Crou's ConfigMap approach is one way to do it. However, since the `settings.xml` file usually contains credentials, I would treat it as [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

You can create a Secret in Kubernetes with command:

```
$ kubectl create secret generic mvn-settings --from-file=settings.xml=./settings.xml
```

The pod definition will be something like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: kaniko
spec:
  containers:
    - name: maven
      image: maven:3-jdk-11-slim
      command:
      - cat
      tty: true
      volumeMounts:
      - name: mvn-settings-vol
        mountPath: /my/path/to
  volumes:
    - name: mvn-settings-vol
      secret:
        secretName: mvn-settings
```

**Advanced/Optional**: If you practice "Infrastructure as Code", you might want to save the manifest file for that secret for recovery. This can be achieved by this command after secret already created:

```
$ kubectl get secrets mvn-settings -o yaml
```

You can keep `secrets.yml` file but do not check into any VCS/Github repo since this version of `secrets.yml` contains unencrypted data.

Some k8s administrators may have [kubeseal](https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets) installed. In that case, I'd recommend using kubeseal to get encrypted version of `secrets.yml`.

```
$ kubectl create secret generic mvn-settings --from-file=settings.xml=./settings.xml --dry-run -o json | kubeseal --controller-name=controller --controller-namespace=k8s-sealed-secrets --format=yaml >secrets.yml

# Actually create secrets
$ kubectl apply -f secrets.yml
```

The `controller-name` and `controller-namespace` should be obtained from k8s administrators. 
This `secrets.yml` contains encrypted data of your `settings.xml` and can be safely checked into VCS/Github repo.

Comment: I agree with your solution but you should add a hint that a secret or config map mounted into the container removes any previous contents of the containing directory. This could lead to some nasty side effects. And imho the paragraph about kubeseal should mention explicitly that only secrets encrypted with kubeseal should be versioned in a VCS just to make sure everyone understands that it's a security risk otherwise even if they just glance at your answer..

Comment: I think you already explained it well. I made some minor edits to make it clearer. My recommendation implies mounting the file to an unused directory `/my/path/to` and explicitly specify the settings in mvn command with `-s /my/path/to/settings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Install Config File Provider Plugin
- Go to Manage Jenkins > Config File Management > Add a new config and insert here your settings.xml
- In your jenkinsfile just put your rtMavenRun inside a configFileProvider  block, and put the same fileId of the jenkins config file you created before

```
    stage('Build Maven') {
                steps {
                    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: 'MavenArtifactorySettingId', variable: 'MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML')]) {
                        retry(count: 3) {
                            rtMavenRun(
                                tool: "Maven 3.6.2", //id specified in Global Tool Configuration
                                pom: 'pom.xml',
                                goals: '-U -s $MAVEN_SETTINGS_XML clean install',
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

this is exactly the pipeline that I used if you want to see more: https://gist.github.com/robertobatts/42da9069e13b61a238f51c36754de97b

Answer (score 0):

If you versioned the settings.xml of the project with the code, it makes sense to build with `mvn install -s settings.xml` using **sh** step. It what I did at work. If settings.xml is not versioned with the project, it indeed makes sens to mount the file with Crou's solution.

To answer your question "Should I use another image with this functionality built in?" I would recommend to avoid a maximum to build custom images because you will end up having to maintain them